# What is the difference between UART port and serial port in a computer?

Tags: drivers

What is the difference, if any, between a UART port and a serial port in a computer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

UART is the abbreviation of Universal Asynchronous Receiver Transmitter, the name of the chip that enables the computer to communicate via a serial line (eg. RS-232, RS-485, RS-422).

The serial port is the RS-232 interface (internally connected to the UART) of the computer.

Comment: I think it is more correct to say, that UART is an implementation of the protocol, of type serial port.

Answer (score 5):

As @SurDin explained some more points I want to add
1.UART takes data parallel and the help of shift register transfer it bit by bit or takes data bit by bit and reform those into parallel form via communication channel like RS-232,RS-485,RS-422.
2.UART has a baud rate generator, transmeter and a receiver.
3.Its baud rate generator gets clocked either by internal clock or by external source.
communication media linked to serial port which internally connected to UART controller.